# Java stream extract list of an element from a list of objects

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an a list of objects.  I want to extract another list of objects from that list.

Original List:

```
List<Types> allTypes

class Types {
 public TypeA
 public TypeB
}
```

// my class does not have a getTypeA method

I want a stream to end up with:

```
List<TypeB> typeBs
```

Is this possible.

I tried this and it does not work.

```
allTypes.stream().map(t -> t.TypeB).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

t.TypeB is not accessible.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: `allTypes.stream().map(t -> t.TypeB).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: @Eritrean, what is `t.TypeB`? Does `class Types` compile for you?  And FYI: With modern versions of Java, `.collect(Collectors.toList())` can be simplified to `.toList()`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. It must be compilable and match your actual source.

Comment: I am hoping the experts here can give me an example.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it compiles just fine. I even wonder how your code runs/compiles given the state of your Types class.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      Types types = new Types();
      types.a = new TypeA();
      types.b = new TypeB();
      List<Types> allTypes = Arrays.asList(types);
      //refer to the varible in t
      List<TypeB> typeB = allTypes.stream().map(t -> t.b).collect(Collectors.toList());
      System.out.println(typeB.get(0).getClass());
    }
}



class Types {
    //besides stating the type, you need to give variable a name
 public TypeA a;
 public TypeB b;
} 

//provide the typea and typeb classes
class TypeB {}
class TypeA {}
```

Comment: of course, you will still need to provide methods, constructors etc. I m just testing the logic to see why the code you provided says typeB is not accessible